# Email HTML: tel:// <a> color

Tags: html-email, email-client

I'm doing a newsletter design and there's a text with a phone number. In many email clients it looks as supposed to but in Gmail it turns the numbers string into a tel:// link to call with gmail's built in diales.

The problem is that the original text was in white and now that Gmail turned it into a link is a darkish blue which completely ruins the design.

Is there a way to avoid gmail to convert it into a phone link or to specify which color it will turn into?

I thought of placing a 123456 so it's already a link, but people reading the email in email clients which doesn't support tel:// links wil be mislead.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's actually Skype that makes those tel:// links and not gmail.

Comment: no, it's gmail. when I click the link it pop ups gmail built in dialer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!:

I did a 123456 to the exact same "selection" of string gmail was replacing with link and no href is being added, lost the call functionality though

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending the email as html, you should be able to specify css rules to change link colors.
Also, you might try putting the phone number in a < pre > tag.